# What do the fields in ls -ali output mean

Tags: linux, shell

The `ls -ali` shell command shows the following output:

```
933442 -rwxrw-r--    10    root   root 2048    Jan 13 07:11 afile.exe
```

What are all the fields in the preceding display?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean and because you added '-i', when you read the man page, it tells you that it's the 'index number', or, inode.

Comment: I got the main idea from there, but index was creating the confusion,now i got it.

Answer (score 45):

```
+--------------+------------------+-----------------+-------+-------+------+-------+-----+-------+-----------+
| index number | file permissions | number of links | owner | group | size | month | day | time  | filename  |
+--------------+------------------+-----------------+-------+-------+------+-------+-----+-------+-----------+
|       933442 | -rwxrw-r--       |              10 | root  | root  | 2048 | Jan   |  13 | 07:11 | afile.exe |
+--------------+------------------+-----------------+-------+-------+------+-------+-----+-------+-----------+
```

Note: month, day and time is the date of last modification.

Comment: May I know what is means by the `number of links` ? Can I have some example? thanks.

Comment: @PanadolChong See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/what-is-the-number-between-file-permission-and-owner-in-ls-l-command-output

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName , as my understanding, a file should have a minimum number of number of links for 1, because 1 is for file itself, but I found that I have a pdf with 0 value, do you know why?

Comment: @PanadolChong Please show us the your input command and output with this case in your original question and not here.